# Most frequently occurring value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have created a sample table here: https://dbfiddle.uk/wUvTIsyN

I am trying to query the most frequently occurring value with group by. Here's my attempt:

```
select pid, propName, Address, City, Response, count(Response) as cr
from Prop
group by 
        pid,
        propName,
        Address,
        City,
        Response
order by
      cr
limit 1;
```

Expected output:

```
pid propName    Address City    Response

1   p1  addr1   c1  2
2   p2  addr2   c2  3
```

`2` and `3` are most frequently occurring responses.

Comment: If you want the most frequently occurring response, you should only group by response, not all the other columns.

Answer (score 3):

You should only group by the column whose frequency you want to get.

```
SELECT response, COUNT(*) AS cr
FROM Prop
GROUP BY response
ORDER BY cr DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You shouldn't include other columns in the `SELECT` list, since they're different for rows with the same response.

If you want to see the rows that have that response, you can join the table with this subquery.

```
SELECT p.*, c.cr
FROM Prop AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT response, COUNT(*) AS cr
    FROM Prop
    GROUP BY response
    ORDER BY cr DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS c ON p.response = c.response
```

Comment: I need the other fields in my result set.

Comment: That's what the second query does

Answer (score 1):

yeah, so I created a an intermediate table res which groups just the way you did it and stores the count of it, then gets the maximum and then equates which one of these tuples have a count=maximum? those tuples(excluding the count) get displayed.
go through the fiddle, it shall be clear:-
https://dbfiddle.uk/f9TTCN9X

AND I have shown all those tuples which have the highest frequency... I think that's what you meant... Please clarify your question if this was not the intended answer.

My 1st query creates the intermediate table res:-

```
create table res(pid int,propname varchar(255),address varchar(255),city varchar(255),response varchar(255),cr int) ;
INSERT INTO res select pid, propName, Address, City, Response, count(Response) as cr
from Prop
group by 
        pid,
        propName,
        Address,
        City,
        Response;
```

My 2nd query does the job:-

```
select pid,propname,address,city,response from res where cr=(select max(cr) from res);
```